# To find Gauss map for 2-sheeted hyperboloid

Tags: differential-geometry

**Find the Gauss map for $2$-sheeted hyperboloid $$x_1^2-x_2^2-\dots-x_{n+1}^2=4$$ , $x_1\gt0$**

I know that the orientation should be taken as $\bar{N}(p)=-\frac{\nabla f}{||\nabla f(p)||}$ where $p\in$ , $S$ is an n-surface.
Then $\bar{N}(p)=(p,N(p))$
I take $p=(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n+1})$ .
I need to find the map $\bar{N}: S \to S^n$.

Comment: You have written the formula for $\bar N$ right in your question. Have you made any attempt to apply that formula?

Comment: Check your tag!

Comment: Yes .I have changed the tag and the formula.

Comment: Your question has been answered by Lee mosher 12 hours ago.

Comment: What's the difference between $N$ and $\overline N$? The equation $\overline N(p) = (p, N(p))$ doesn't seem to make sense, especially given the other equations with $\overline N$.